# How to add a new file in a current repository of github

Tags: github, repository

I've created a new repo on github, and while my old repos have a **"create new file"** button, my new repo doesn‘t.

How do I get my new repo to have this button?

Answer (score 0):

You have to press on the new repository. Then you come to the view, where you can see all files and folders in this repository. There is also the button "*create new file*" (look at the picture):

[image]

Here you have also a [tutorial](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/creating-new-files) how to create a new file in a repository on github.

I hope this helps you and fixes your problem